# Upgrading Flyway 4.1.2 to 6.4.4 results in NoSuchMethodError: org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.getLocations()

Tags: java, spring, flyway

I've been upgrading a Spring application from 1.5.4 to 2.3.1. Subsequently, Flyway was bumped up from 4.1.2 to 6.4.4. The problem I'm facing now, is that when some Flywaytests run, the following Exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String[] org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.getLocations()'
    at org.flywaydb.test.junit.FlywayTestExecutionListener.locationsMigrationHandling(FlywayTestExecutionListener.java:313)
    at org.flywaydb.test.junit.FlywayTestExecutionListener.dbResetWithAnotation(FlywayTestExecutionListener.java:272)
    at org.flywaydb.test.junit.FlywayTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(FlywayTestExecutionListener.java:191)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    ...
```

This is my Flyway configuration:

```java
@Configuration
public class FlywayConfig {
    @Bean
    public Flyway flyway(final DataSource dataSource) {
        return Flyway.configure().dataSource(dataSource).load();
    }

    @Bean
    public FlywayMigrationInitializer flywayInitializer(final Flyway flyway) {
        return new FlywayMigrationInitializer(flyway, null);
    }

}
```

Furthermore, here is snippit of my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
   id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.3.1.RELEASE"
   id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
   ...
}

dependencies {
  compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aspects'
  compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
  compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator"
  compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf"
  compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
  compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
  compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"

  runtime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-properties-migrator")

  compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons'
  compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa'

  compile 'org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas'
  compile 'org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core'

  compile group: 'org.flywaydb', name: 'flyway-core'

  testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test'
  testCompile group: 'org.flywaydb.flyway-test-extensions', name: 'flyway-spring-test', version: '4.0.1'
  ...
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your pom.xml or build.gradle? Or better - a list of dependencies (with versions) for Spring Framework, Spring Boot and Flyway (if explicitly declared)?

Comment: @AlexShesterov is that enough? While copying I realized I have the version 4.0.1  of `org.flywaydb.flyway-test-extensions`. This might be the reason? Which version should I use?

Comment: @AlexShesterov I upgraded to 6.4.0 and the error is gone. Thanks for pointing me into the right direction!

Comment: Maybe you could add the solution as an answer, to potentially help others, and maybe getting some rep ;)

Comment: @AlexShterov I'd prefer if you did so, because you're the one who helped me figure it out. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a mismatch of Flyway versions used by Spring / Spring Boot and flyway-test-extensions.

See the following issue on GitHub: https://github.com/flyway/flyway-test-extensions/issues/59

Please upgrade the version of `org.flywaydb.flyway-test-extensions:flyway-spring-test` to (at least) `5.1.0`:

```
testCompile group: 'org.flywaydb.flyway-test-extensions', name: 'flyway-spring-test', version: '5.0.1'
```